# Where does Safari store material from "fbcdn.net"?

Tags: macos, safari, facebook, privacy

If I **disconnect from internet**, launch Safari, open Preferences→Privacy→Manage website data, and click Remove All, everything vanishes **except** a cache from fbcdn.net.

Selecting that only and clicking Remove also has no change.

I know that belongs to Facebook, but why can't I get rid of it?

Internet was disconnected, and no tabs were open, so it can't (shouldn't) be that Facebook instantly reloads it.

Trying to find it failed.  `sudo find / -print | grep -i …` with various things (fb, cdn, facebook, etc.) for … turns up nothing that seems like a possible fit.  (Though it does show a heck of a lot of cruft from apps I haven't used in years!)

Comment: How many items do you have saved in your Safari reading list? I would probably repeat this restarting the OS once internet was disabled. In my case, emptying data works even with internet connected. Just closed all windows and deleted and it’s clean.

Comment: I was surprised to find several Facebook links in the reading list.  Saw no reason why I would have saved any of them.  Deleted them all, and the fbcdn is still "stuck."

Comment: It’s a mystery. Pinned tabs and reading list are the only “persistent” stores for offline reading. It must be some extension or plug in or just the database files safari maintains are somehow corrupt. If you make a new account on the Mac, does it clear data like I describe above?